# React Fontawesome Icon on Button not Allowing Id to be Accessed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, font-awesome

I am using react fontawesome in my project. Under the render function of my component I have the following which maps a school onto the page and then I want a button with an edit icon to perform an action. My code for the button looks as below:

```
      { this.state.myschools.map( (school) => (
          <Row key={school.id}>
            <Col><p>{school.name}</p></Col>
            { school.deaths.length > 0 ? <Col md="2"><button id={school.id} className="likelink" onClick={this.goToSchoolDeathList}>View Deaths</button></Col> : <Col md="2"></Col> }
            <Col><button id={school.id} onClick={this.editSchool}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEdit} /></button></Col>
          </Row>
        ))}
```

The editSchool function is as:

```
  editSchool(e) {
      console.log("School Id");
      console.log(e.target.id);
  }
```

If I click on the empty space around the font awesome icon then the id is logged to the console. If I only click on the area where the icon exits then the id is not logged. I want the user to be able to click on any part of the button including the fa icon and to capture the school id.

I have tried adding the onClick event and the id attribute to the "FontAwesomeIcon" component, but that still doesn't work.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is one of the common pitfall you learn during your time with React. Rest assure, we have all fallen into this pit.

There are few AHA moments here.

**1st Aha:** React doesn't have a usual way to let you get element attribute in an event (an `e` in your example).

That being said, you can still access to the `button` element by `e.target` and use JavaScript to get attribute.

**Solution #1 JavaScript getAttribute**

```
editSchool(e) {
  console.log("School Id");
  console.log(e.target.getAttribute('id'));
}
```

e.target will be the HTML Element that you click, and we can use JavaScript way to get attribute. (Please Note that, ***Javascript way*** is not React way)

But there are another way and you'll see this way more often.

**Solution #2 You can define a function directly in a render**

```
<button id={school.id} onClick={e => this.editSchool(school.id)}>
```

Please be careful about this another pitfall,

**2nd Aha:** Bind onClick to function, not result of a function.

Don't do this

```
<button id={school.id} onClick={this.editSchool(scholl.id)}> // This is incorrect
```

The thing is `onClick` prop expect a function to call when someone click.

The first one we define a function `e => this.editSchool(school.id)` and bind onClick with the newly defined function.

While the second, we just bind onClick to a "result" of function `this.editSchool(school.id)`, which is not a function.

Comment: Not sure if I solve the real problem here... I see other possible problems too, let me know if this one doesn't help.

Comment: Many thanks, I used solution two and it seems to be working,

Answer (score 0):

first assign id to the button like `<button id={todo.id} onClick={handleClick}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash}/></button>` then get id in the function like

`const handleClick = evt =>  {let id=(evt.target.closest("button").getAttribute('id')) console.log(id)}`